# trying to understand the use of #pragma region in Arduino in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded

I am using Arduino for interfacing with fingerprint module. I was trying to understand the code of fingerprint module. i know the purpose of pragma to instruct the compiler for operation. but i want to know how it is handled in Arduino. 
is it handled in linking file?

```
#pragma region -= Command_Packet Definitions =-
#pragma endregion
#pragma region -= Response_Packet Definitions =-
#pragma endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

It is handled by preprocessor. All directives starting with `#` are.

`#pragma region` is common in MSVC code but may not be recognized by other compilers. `#pragma`s are often nonportable. So when coding, it's better to avoid `#pragma`.

Comment: okay. I am not sure about MSVC. But i am sure it is used in most of the embedded coding to locate the blocks.

Comment: `#pragma`s make the code more readable. Nothing else. Since Arduino code are not designed to be portable, there're no problems about `#pragma`s.

Comment: #pragma is not necessarily handled by the preprocessor.  Some of them end up in the output of the preprocessor to be handled by the compiler.  This particular one SEEMS to be something that's only used by the IDE for display purposes.